# Compact complex surfaces having infinitely many negative curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I am trying to find a (smooth) compact complex surface $X$ so that the set of irreducible curves $C$ on $X$ for which $C.C<0$ is infinite. Do any of you know of an example. Thanks.

Comment: Any (nonconstant) elliptic surface with infinite Mordell-Weil group should do. 

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2179/curves-with-negative-self-intersection-in-the-product-of-two-curves/67008#67008

Comment: So I asked a redundant question. 

Comment: No not redundant, just quite well-known. Look at references for when the cone of curves is not finitely generated. For example, Kovacs' paper 'The cone of curves on a K3 surface' is a nice starting point. In particular, you'll see K3 surfaces with infinitely many $(-2)$-curves. The Fermat quartic $x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4=0$ is one example. Also, if a surface has a large automorphism group and contains one negative curve it typically contains infinitely many - this happens for example for Enriques surfaces, see eg http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52397/are-there-2-curves-on-an-enriques-surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blow up $\mathbb P^2$ at 9 points. See e.g. Hartshorne exercise 5.4.15e) and the reference there.

Comment: Some more details: if you blow up the plane at 9 in general position, then acting by Cremona transformations gives a sequence of rational curves of arbitrarily high degree through the 9 points that pull back to divisors of self intersection -1. See Artie Prendergast's note http://www.iag.uni-hannover.de/~prendergast/Papers/coneofcurves.pdf for more details.